# Sort a view by country - according to the translated countries

Tags: i18n-l10n, location, views

I have a view displaying some nodes of a content type. Each node has a location assigned (with the [location module](http://drupal.org/project/location)).

I want to group and sort the results by countries. The grouping works fine, and the sorting is *almost* fine too.

It does sort by country, but it does it using the *english* countries' names.

However, my website is in french, so I want it to sort using the *french* countries' names.

Most of the countries are fine, but some are not the same. For example: `South Korea` is `Corée du Sud` in french, so it's not the same order.

Views uses the english name to sort, I want it to use the current language (here french, but it's a multilingual website, so also english when it is).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that views uses SQL to sort, since that is a lot easier and faster and it otherwise would be required to load all the records and sort them with PHP, before selecting which to show, which is a massive resources waste if you have a lot of records and use paging.

A simple solution to this problem, is to create a work around. Since the country names is stored in english, you can create a field that you hide from the user where you store the French country name. You can then in your view use this field when sorting. You would need to write a bit of code - in a custom module you create - to hide the field in the UI and automatically set the correct value based on the country the user selected in the interface. This can all be done with `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: So I have to create a new field in the database? This seems like an issue to raise in views' (or location) issues queue.

Comment: Just create a new field with the Field UI.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well... that seems damn ugly, but I guess there's no other way.